# Adding Jquery to WordPress Menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic, menu

I have a demo site set up located at http://www.threecell.com/demo. Currently, the fadein rollover state for the menu is set using CSS3. I'm hoping to get assistance with using Jquery to duplicate the animation effect so that the site is displayable in IE9.

I'll be honest in saying that I'm unsure as to the simplest and best Jquery script to use for something as seemingly simple as this. This is the code I attempted to use but ultimately needed help on integrating it with the existing WordPress theme. Any help in this area would be most appreciated.

```
var hoverColour = "green";

$(function(){
    $("a.hoverBtn").show("fast", function() {
        $(this).wrap("<div class=\"hoverBtn\">");
        $(this).attr("class", "");
    });

    //display the hover div
    $("div.hoverBtn").show("fast", function() {
        //append the background div
        $(this).append("<div></div>");

        //get link's size
        var wid = $(this).children("a").width();
        var hei = $(this).children("a").height();

        //set div's size
        $(this).width(wid);
        $(this).height(hei);
        $(this).children("div").width(wid);
        $(this).children("div").height(hei);

        //on link hover
        $(this).children("a").hover(function(){
            //store initial link colour
            if ($(this).attr("rel") == "") {
                $(this).attr("rel", $(this).css("color"));
            }
            //fade in the background
            $(this).parent().children("div")
                .stop()
                .css({"display": "none", "opacity": "1"})
                .fadeIn("slow");
            //fade the colour
            $(this) .stop()
                .css({"color": $(this).attr("rel")})
                .animate({"color": hoverColour}, 350);
        },function(){
            //fade out the background
            $(this).parent().children("div")
                .stop()
                .fadeOut("slow");
            //fade the colour
            $(this) .stop()
                .animate({"color": $(this).attr("rel")}, 250);
        });
    });
});
```

The style for this script is located below:

```
.hoverBtn {
    position:       relative;
    float:          left;
    background:     black url(images/navBG.png) repeat-x 0 0 scroll;
}
.hoverBtn a {   
    position:       relative;
    z-index:        2;
    display:        block;
    width:          100px;
    height:         30px;
    line-height:    30px;
    text-align:     center;
    font-size:      1.1em;
    text-decoration:    none;
    color:          blue;
    background:     transparent none repeat-x 0 0 scroll;
}
.hoverBtn div {
    display:        none;
    position:       absolute;
    z-index:        1;
    top:            0px;
    background:     white url(images/navHover.png) repeat-x 0 0 scroll;
    color: black;
}
```

Again, I'm open to using any script that works. The scripts above were posted back in 2009 so while they may still work, I don't mind using what's most up to date.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this function for menu in wordpress site.**

```
function home_top_menu()
{
    var currentParent = '';
    var pos = '';
    jQuery("#.menu ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    jQuery(".menu li").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(268);
            },function(){
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
    jQuery(".menu .sub-menu").hover(function(){
        currentParent = $(this).parent('li').attr('class');
        pos = currentParent.indexOf('current-menu-parent',0);
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('current-menu-parent');
    },function(){
        if(pos == '-1')
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('current-menu-parent');
    });
    jQuery('#accessMenu ul.menu li a').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).css('background','none');
        jQuery(this).find('span').css('background','none');                 
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response and code. Could you please provide some assistance as to where this function should go and where to call it in the header section?